# Cannot open server 'servername' requested by the login. Client is not allowed to access the server. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Tags: azure-sql-database

Im trying to connect to azure sql database in SSMS from a server on my network.
I am getting the below error:

```
Cannot open server 'rcsi-replica' requested by the login. Client is not allowed to access the server. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

[image]

Usually this is due to the server level firewall, but the database owner has confirmed they have a firewall rule in place for my server IP.

My next guess is a local firewall on my network, but the error message indicates it can see the database but is not allowed to access it.

Is there anything else that could block me from connecting to this database?

Comment: Once check your credentials i.e. username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Connection error 40914 relates to virtual network rules on the firewall configuration and not to IP address rules on the Azure SQL firewall. This mean Azure SQL wants you to add a virtual network rule, but you are at your office network and not connecting from an Azure VNet. Then that probably means the database owner has configured a private endpoint for the Azure SQL database, he has disabled public IP address access to configure that endpoint and you may need to configure a [proxy](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-316-connecting-to-private-endpoint-of-azure-sql/ba-p/3731257) or a VPN tunneling to access it.